# iFrame border-radius displays visual gaps

Tags: html, css, iframe

When adding a border-radius on an iFrame's parent div, the border doesn't perfectly fit the iFrame, even when they are assigned the same width and height values.

I've added arrows pointing to the visual gaps in the resulting image below.  Screenshot is from the latest version of Chrome (March, 2016).

---

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="mapFrame">
    <iFrame class="googleMap" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=sanfrancisco&amp;output=embed" width="500" height="400"></iFrame>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.mapFrame
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    height; 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `.mapFrame iframe {border: none}`?  From my computer (also latest chrome), it appears to be the default iframe border.  You might also consider making the iframe `display:block` as inline elements tend to have line height and letter spacing that throws off pixel exact rendering.

Comment: Makes perfect sense and works great.  Thanks, Joseph.

Answer (score -1):

Border radius isn't well supported or consistent yet. If you want the desired effect, try using DIV's around the element and use graphics instead, with an overflow of hidden in your CSS. You might want to look into the sliding doors technique if you're iframe varies in height.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Please don't just copy & paste answers from 5 years earlier